# Why is this sequence true?

Tags: javascript

```
(function() { console.log (1);
  setTimeout(function(){console.log(2)}, 1000);
  setTimeout(function(){console.log(3)}, 0); 
  console.log(4); 
})();
```

Output is:
1
4
3
2

Why doesn't 3 come before 4, since the timeout is 0ms, shouldn't it execute immedately, and thus come before 4?

Comment: I wouldn't make that assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timeouts are pushed to the bottom of the processing stack after the "block" is finished. So this is how the engine sees it:

```
Log 1
Set a timeout 1s later to log 2
Set a timeout 0s later to log 3
Log 4
Run all timeouts
```

Comment: Technically, it's not a stack, but whatever :P

Answer (score 1):

Because the execution of the current function will finish before any of the timeouts are run.

```
setTimeout(function(){console.log(3)}, 0);
```

Adds a timeout function but the current function is finished before any of them will fire.